# Problem installing Python-Dev

Tags: apt, software-installation, python, python-2.7

I am having trouble installing `python-dev`. It all started when I tried to install another Python package and got the error:

```
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev.
```

I tried `sudo apt-get install python-dev` but got the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-dev : Depends: python2.7-dev (>= 2.7.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So then I tried `sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev` and got the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python2.7-dev : Depends: python2.7 (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu3) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libpython2.7 (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu3) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
```

I have tried most everything in the post [unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies). I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and I have everything updated. I have done `apt-get clean` and `apt-get autoclean`. I have tried `apt-get -f install` and all variations on that theme. I have cleaned up my PPA. I even tried using Aptitude, and though it did a lot of clean up, the result was the same.

I really want to be able to install python-dev. How can I make this happen? At this point, I am willing to consider extreme options, whatever they may be.

Comment: The problem isn't installing python-dev.  The problem is getting src and include folders propogated to your virtualenv.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions there? I was using `--system-site-packages`.

Comment: Read this: http://pythoncentral.org/setting-up-the-python-environment-with-virtualenv/ it explains how it actually works.

Comment: @CallmeV This is a great post, but sadly doesn't address the problem I'm having getting Python-Dev to install.

Comment: Do you have `python` installed? (`sudo apt-get install python`)

Comment: @RodrigoMartins Oh yes, I have written many thousands of lines of Python code. But so far using only the standard libraries, thus the need to get python-dev working.

Comment: @theJollySin - what version of ubuntu are you using?  Please disable all PPAs and run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.  Paste the output to paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Here is what you were looking for: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5775975/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This bit:

```
 python2.7-dev : Depends: python2.7 (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu3) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
```

suggests that you are using some mismatched repositories, or have some apt-pins in place keeping the version dependencies from lining up. I think, specifically, `python-2.7 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1` is in the `Precise-proposed` repository and the `2.7.3-0ubuntu3` version is in Precise/main proper, so you may be preferring -proposed for some but not all packages.

Can you edit your question to include the output of:

```
apt-cache policy python2.7-dev
apt-cache policy python2.7
```

and maybe:

```
apt-cache show python2.7
```

...

Reading the apt-cache output from your pastebin, it looks like you have the python2.7 `2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1` from `precise-updates/main`  installed, but `python2.7-dev` is from `precise/main`. I think your install media or an earlier "apt-get update" included the `precise-updates` repository, but it's not in your current sources.list.

I think you'll be able to get the install going after adding `precise-updates` and then `apt-get update`.

```
echo "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise-updates.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```

Comment: I pasted the response to `apt-cache policy python2.7` and the like here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5775963/

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't install numpy with pip, use the package Ubuntu provides:

```
dennis@koekblik:~$ apt-cache show python-numpy
Package: python-numpy
Priority: optional
Section: python
Installed-Size: 7616
...
```

As to your actual problem: try installing `python2.7-dev`. It will likely fail but should give you a better error message.

Comment: Okay, your first statement: there are other packages (like `gdal`) that would be much easier if I could install through PIP. Your second point, I can try that and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: I agree that pip is a useful tool, but please stick to Ubuntu packages as much as possible, much easier for updating. And if you use pip to install packages, you might want to create yourself a virtualenv so you don't need to install as root into /usr/local.

Comment: Okay, I will try to stick to Ubuntu packages. But this whole problem started because I can get `numpy` working fine, but can't get `numpy` imported inside a `virtualenv`. Having a working `virtualenv` system for Python development is definitely the goal. Thanks again.

Comment: That's a different question though :) Use a virtualenv with --system-site-packages to get access to what's installed via apt.

Answer (score 3):

fastest solution:

- Install (`sudo apt-get install synaptic`) Synaptic Package Manager and start it
- Click on **Settings-Repositories**
- Select **Download from: Main Server**
- Click <kbd>Close</kbd> then click on <kbd>Reload</kbd>.
- Mark `python-dev` for installation and Synaptic will also mark all dependencies of `python-dev` (`libexpat1-dev, libssl-dev, libssl-doc, python2.7-dev, zlib1g-dev`).

I have just resolved the same problem on freshly installed Ubuntu x86 12.04.3.

Answer (score 0):

For those that encounter this problem, first try and run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and try to install again

Comment: It is not necessary to give such introduction. Just give your answer. As per my experience, not always `unmet dependency` can be solved by using `sudo apt-get update`