# Completely unable to install python2.7-dev

Tags: apt, virtualbox, python-2.7

Am totally stuck!

Am unable completely to install python2.7-dev on my Ubuntu13.04. I have tried all the tricks mentioned on this site (askubuntu.com) and many other sites on the web but still nothing!

Am running Ubuntu 13.04 64bit on a virtualbox, but every time I run `sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev`, I get the following error;

```
python2.7-dev : Depends: python2.7 (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.5) but 2.7.4-2ubuntu3 is to be installed
                 Depends: libpython2.7 (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.5) but 2.7.4-2ubuntu3 is to be installed
                 Depends: libexpat1-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried to do **apt-get update**, but still nothing! I've even tried installing Python2.7 from sources, but still nothing doing!

Is there a single package with all the dependencies I can download, that can just install everything (Python2.7-dev) or is there another trick I can use to get the Python-dev headers installed on my machine.

Hint:
I've noticed when I run `sudo apt-get update` , somewhere along the updates I've seen some errors;

```
...
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-security Release
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [98.7 kB]
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources         
  404  Not Found
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages  
  404  Not Found
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
...
```

On my **precise-updates.list** file is a single entry;

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
```

I don't know if that might help

Help!

Paul

Comment: Can you post your sources.list? Also please post links to what other solutions you have tried?\.

Comment: 13.04 is no more supported, a consequence of this may be that the repositories for this release have been emptied or simply deleted (reason you get a 404 error). Upgrade to the last supported release (14.04 LTS) may solve this issue.

Comment: Tried that suggestion  from the link give by @karel, failed! cool let me try installing 14.04LTS see how it goes ...

Comment: @rishiaq, one of the suggestions I tried from askubuntu.com are http://askubuntu.com/questions/275861/problem-installing-python-dev

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all,

@Benoit idea worked for me, Installed the latest Ubuntu14.04LTS and apt-get install python2.7-dev installed well!

Paul