# How can I install python-dev off apt-get?

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, python

I have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275861/problem-installing-python-dev) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631135/python-h-missing-from-ubuntu-12-04) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282231/ubuntu-i-have-python-but-gcc-cant-find-python-h) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379929/cant-find-python-h-file-on-centos)

None of those install python-dev, I got my amd64 system, 14.04 up and running, as I try to install wagtail, a django cms, I get the error:

```
     pysass.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

     #include <Python.h>

                        ^

    compilation terminated.

    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
    Cleaning up...
    Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/
    libsass/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace
    ('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ojWg1O-record/install-
    record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in 
    /tmp/pip_build_root/libsass
    Storing debug log for failure in /home/payload/.pip/pip.log
```

How can I fix this and install the package?

It's because of the missing `Python.h`c header which is included in the `python-dev` package.

When I tried the above links, it says:

`apt-get install python-dev`

```
Package python-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python

E: Package 'python-dev' has no installation candidate
```

for `apt-get install python2.7-dev`

```
Package python2.7-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python2.7-dev' has no installation candidate
```

I have researched on the [debian archives](https://packages.debian.org/sid/python-all-dev) and found a package for `python 2.7.8-1` but that couldn't be installed.

Tried [this on launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-defaults) too but doesn't work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you sure you are doing it right?

This is my output for `# apt-get install python2.7-dev`

```
root@olympus:/home/zeus# apt-get install python2.7-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libexpat1-dev libpython2.7-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libexpat1-dev libpython2.7-dev python2.7-dev
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 22.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 35.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Try doing this as root (`su`)

Also, try running `# apt update` and make sure *Multiverse and universe* are enabled (See [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)). I also got *backports* enabled in my system, not sure whether that makes a difference in this case.

Comment: http://imgur.com/dI6n3Pq this is my screenshot. how to enable multiverse and universe?

Comment: @John: Type the following command: `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"`

Comment: +1.. I was getting similar error when trying to install using python3.5. After Installing **python3.5-dev** the error was gone

Comment: I had the same `#include <Python.h>` error and running `sudo apt-get install python-dev` fixed it. This is with python2.7.

Comment: I tried as told and it works.

Answer (score 2):

> try this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

> instead of python-dev where package "python3" contains python3 and python-dev

Comment: I just ran into this with the pyhon-image from docker-hub. They have upgraded to Debian Bookworm, in which things have apparently moved around. They left a hint in my error-message saying `python-dev-is-python3`.